# android opencv 3.4.1 Build command failed. Undefined reference to

Tags: java, c++, opencv, android

I am trying to use opencv cpp method Stitcher from stitching.hpp, but I still getting error. It looks like i do not have definitions of functions but do not know why. I set up my CMakeList.txt:

```html
set(pathToProject C:/Users/Filip/AndroidStudioProjects/PanoStich)
set(pathToOpenCV C:/Users/Filip/Downloads/OpenCV-android-sdk)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE on)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=gnu++11 -v")
include_directories(${pathToOpenCV}/sdk/native/jni/include/)

add_library( 
             native-lib
             SHARED
             src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp )

add_library( lib_opencv SHARED IMPORTED )

set_target_properties(lib_opencv PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${pathToProject}/app/src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libopencv_java3.so)

find_library( 
              log-lib
              log )

target_link_libraries(
                   native-lib
                   lib_opencv
                   $\{log-lib} )
```

Error I got is on picture below

[Error returned while building](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owWPp.png)

Station: Macbook Pro, Virtual Windows 64b, Android Studio, Opencv4Mobile 3.4.1

Answer (score 0):

This is a know issue in opencv for android starting from 3.4.1. This is due to java wrapper not being built for stitching module. This issue is present even in 3.4.3. The only solution I was able to find is to build opencv for android. Once you download the source code, Find CMakeList.txt under opencv _src_dir/modules/stitching and add java to WRAP.

opencv issue - https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/11595

I am still in the process of building opencv for android. Please let us know if you have found any other solution.